# Azure VM Scale Sets Internal Loadbalancer

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is it possible in any to create a VM Scale Set with an internal load balancer using private IP for the Front end instead of a public IP?

Comment: Did you try it? Where did you ran into?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible in any to create a VM Scale Set with an internal load
>   balancer using private IP for the Front-end instead of a public IP?

Yes, we can use PowerShell to deploy VMSS with the internal load balancer.
I create a VM in the same Vnet work as a jump box and use PowerShell to deploy VMSS with the internal load balancer. Here is my test:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
More information about creating VMSS with Powershell, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-vmss-powershell-creating).
More information about creating internal load balancer, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-ps).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful! I am trying to build the internal load balancer in with the Scale set in a json template.