# Azure scaleset private DNS

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

Is there any possibility to link a scaleset to an internal Azure Load Balancer? I want to have a private scaleset that's not opened to the public for increasing security.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to link a scaleset to an internal Azure Load
>   Balancer?

Yes, we can use PowerShell to deploy VMSS with the internal load balancer.

About use PowerShell to create VMSS, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-create-vmss).

About use PowerShell to create internal load balancer, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-ps).

Here a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209387/azure-vm-scale-sets-internal-loadbalancer), please refer to it.